# Can you continue a save from the digital version with the disc version?

Tags: ps3, dragon-age-origins

I have the digital PSN version of Dragon Age Origins on PS3 as a recent PS Plus title.

If I were to start a game on this version and bought the retail ["Ultimate Edition"](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Age:_Origins_Ultimate_Edition) of the game, which includes the base game and all add-ons on disc, could I continue my save file of the digital version with the disc version and use the save to play the add-ons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should work just fine.  When I did this on the Xbox 360, I just used the disc to install the DLC from the Ultimate Edition and then still played the digital copy on my hard drive.